# PHP mail() works but wp_mail() does not

Tags: email, wp-mail

I'm totally lost by the mail function in WordPress (WP 4.6 multisites).

I tested locally (on my localhost) WordPress send mail. This works fine at first sight (I don't really know why because I've never configured any SMTP server address in WordPress). When a user is created, a notification mail is correctly sent to the right address.

**BUT**, if I try to use the wp_mail() function in one of my theme pages, it just doesn't work! If I use instead the mail() php function, it works perfectly.
(php mail() is set on my smtp server 'smtp' which is set on my provider's SMTP server, with a valid 'sender address')

There is about the same question [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/218171/phps-mail-function-works-wps-wp-mail-does-not) (**Dead link, question was removed**). The difference is that in my case, wp_mail() **does work** in the dashboard part but not in my theme...
MANY thanks to you for a track, Pierre.  (hope this post will be posted ! :)

Comment: There is a bug relating to 4.6 which minght cause it depending on server configuration and maybe the email addresses being actually used (sorry, don't remember its number) which might or might not be the cause for this (as far as I understand it relates to the legality of the sender address that triggers the issue)

Comment: Did my answer resolve your question? If so, please upvote it and click the green checkmark to let the community know. Thanks.

Comment: downvoted as without more debuging effort you are left with only guessing as to what the cause might be

Answer (score 2):

Add action method `phpmailer_init` in the theme functions.php. And configure settings with your SMTP server details.

```
add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'phpmailer_ss_SMTP' );
function phpmailer_ss_SMTP( $phpmailer )
{
    $phpmailer->IsSMTP();
    $phpmailer->Host        = 'mail.domainname.com';
    $phpmailer->Port        = 588; 
    $phpmailer->SMTPAuth    = true; 
    $phpmailer->Username    = 'info@domainname.com';
    $phpmailer->Password    = 'Set Password';
    $phpmailer->From        = 'info@domainname.com';
    $phpmailer->FromName    = 'Website Name';
    $phpmailer->AuthType    = 'LOGIN';
    $phpmailer->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
    $phpmailer->SMTPSecure  =''; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The plugin, [WP Mail SMTP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/), looks like a possible solution to use the `wp_mail()` properly on your localhost. According to the description:

> Reconfigures the `wp_mail()` function to use SMTP instead of `mail()` and creates an options page to manage the settings.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ethan for answering....I just precise that I AM my own hosting so far, and the problem is on my localhost, this is the point ! haven't given the smallest parameter concerning a SMTP server to WP, and despite this, it sends a mail with wp_mail() and it WORKS fine in the dashboard part...My second problem is that wp_mail() doesn't work in the theme page...

Comment: Okay, so everything you are doing is on your `localhost`. From reading your question, I was under the impression that your tests works on the localhost and then you tried it on your live online server. What are you using to run your localhost? [WAMP](http://wampserver.com), [XAMPP](https://apachefriends.org), etc. Using the mailing functionality usually doesn;t work because extra configuration is needed.

Comment: I am on Linux apche2 php7.

Comment: By the way, my smtp server works fine and can send a mail (using the SMTP address of my provider "Free" and my "Free" email adress as sender) and so does my php function mail()

Comment: @Pierre, those are the specs that you gave me for your localhost server. But what did you use to set them up? For example, I'm using [WAMP](http://wampserver.com/en) as my tool to set up the environment ([screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/CSaJh2t.png)). Like I said, sending mail on a localhost isn't very practical and I'd recommend testing out the `wp_mail()` function on a live server.

Comment: I understand your point on wp_mail() and I agree that it will be better to check it on my (future) real host provider. For the precision concerning the configuration of my local server : I don't use any WAMP or LAMP, I just setup myself a httpd daemon (apache), a mysql server and I setup my php config : All that make a server (at least, I used to do this long before any ?AMP appear)...Thanks again for your help...

Comment: I've update my question with a possible plugin for your solution. let me know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers give good solutions to checking into setting up SMTP, which you should do regardless of whether it's your actual problem or not.

However, based on your description, I don't think that's the actual problem here. It is more likely that where you are trying to use `wp_mail()` the function has not been loaded yet.

Are you running WP in debug mode?  If not, enable it and test again.  If you get an error that the `wp_mail()` function is undefined, then your issue is in fact that `wp_mail()` (and pluggable.php) is not loaded and is not available for use.

This happens when people don't hook a process to a specific action, or if they don't know the typical order of actions and use a hook that fires before the function is loaded.

`wp_mail()` is a pluggable function, which means that plugins can alter it. Pluggable functions are loaded late in the process so that plugins can define them first.

Hooking a process that uses a pluggable function to something like the `init` action will help since all pluggable functions are loaded at that point.  So your process should be something like the following:

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_hooked_function' );
function my_hooked_function() {
    // doing something here...
    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message );
}
```

If the process you are doing is in your theme's functions.php but not hooked to an action, hooking to the appropriate action will solve your problem.

An alternative that you'll see mentioned but is less desirable is to simply make sure pluggable.php is included:

```
function my_not_hooked_function() {
    include_once( ABSPATH . '/wp-includes/pluggable.php' );
    // doing something here...
    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message );
}
```